# Encoding with C# and Java

Tags: java

I have got to make the same function in Java and C#, but the result are not the same.

My code in C# :

```csharp
    string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"crc.xml");

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlString);

    // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
           
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);

    // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
         sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

And my code in Java :

```java
    string xmlstring = Files.readString(Paths.get("crc.xml"));
    MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] digest = m.digest(xmlstring.getbytes());
    String hash = new BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16);
    System.out.println(hash);
```

In C# I have this result :

> F5F8B2F361FEA6EA30F24BEBAA5BDE3A

But in Java I have this result :

> 8fb40aad49fbf796b82a2faa11cda764

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think the C# byte is unsigned and the java byte is signed, that can cause the difference

Comment: C# is using Encoding.ASCII but Java uses UTF-8

Comment: If you want to calculate the MD5 of a file, you should **never** read the file content into a `String`, because that already includes a level of interpretation (namely decoding the charset) that is not necessary and can be actively harmful to the attempt. Just read the `byte[]` directly (or even better, stream the `byte[]` data, because there's no reason to have it all in memory at once). In Java the direct replacement would be `Files.readAllBytes()`. It seems .NET has a `ReadAllBytes` as well.

Comment: (the only reason I didn't post this as an answer is that I'm not sure that this is the specific reason for the difference here, but it is definitely an issue here).

Answer (score 1):

Codebrane say it. Use

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UFT8.GetBytes(xmlString);
```

instead of

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlString);
```